# Unable to get list of files in directory from MonoGame

Tags: c#, io, xna, directory, monogame

I was porting one of my XNA projects into Monogame when I ran into a interesting issue. Since as a windows 8 user my application is sandboxed, I can't use the Directory.GetFiles method I'm used to to pull up a list of files in a content directory. My goal is get get a list of files in a content directory like (myappinstalllocation\Content\TypeofContent\XmlFiles).

In Xna I'd use:

```
string[] skillFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
```

I tried the following code from msdn, but the async methods sometimes fail to return for a couple minutes and sometimes not at all:

```
string[] fileNames = SystemIO.getFileNames(path, "xml").Result;

public static async Task<string[]> getFileNames(string pPath, string pExt)
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(pPath);

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> contents = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file in contents)
        {
            if (file.FileType.Contains(pExt))
            {
                results.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

        return results.ToArray();
    }
```

I don't know if MonoGame provides a way to get the file names or if WinStore API does. I;d like to load as much of my content dynamically as possible so I'm hoping that this is doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is a deadlock.  Using `Task.Result` on the UI thread will do that.  Try using `await` instead:

```
string[] fileNames = await SystemIO.getFileNames(path, "xml");
```

`await` is non-blocking, and allows the UI thread to do other things while your call to `getFileNames` is completing.

Check out Stephen Cleary's excellent blog article on the subject: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: This worked. i also had to add the async keyword to the methods that called getFilenames()